# Perform a function on a dataframe across variable number of columns after removing zeros

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function where I can pass a function as a variable to perform on a variable number of columns, after removing zeros. I'm not too comfortable with ellipses yet, and I'm guessing this is where the problem is arising. The function is using all the values in the specified rows, summarizing them based on the selected function, and then mutating that one value. I'd like to maintain the function across the row (e.g. `rowMeans`)

Example:

```
# Setup dataframe
a <- 1:5
b <- c(0, 4, 3, 0, 1)
c <- c(5:1)
d <- c(2, 0, 1, 0, 4)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)



FUNexcludeZero <- function(function_name, ...){

  # Match function name 
  FUN <- match.fun(function_name)

  # get all the values - I'm sure this is the problem, need to somehow turn it back into a df?
  vals <- unlist(list(...))

  # Remove 0's and perform function
  valsNo0 <- vals[vals != 0]
  compiledVals <- FUN(valsNo0)
  return(compiledVals) 
}

df %>% 
  mutate(foo = FUNexcludeZero(function_name = 'sd', a, b))

  a b c d      foo
1 1 0 5 2 1.457738
2 2 4 4 0 1.457738
3 3 3 3 1 1.457738
4 4 0 2 0 1.457738
5 5 1 1 4 1.457738

df %>% 
  mutate(foo = FUNexcludeZero(function_name = 'min', a, b))

  a b c d foo
1 1 0 5 2   1
2 2 4 4 0   1
3 3 3 3 1   1
4 4 0 2 0   1
5 5 1 1 4   1

# Try row-function (same error occurs with rowMeans)
df %>% 
  mutate(foo = FUNexcludeZero(function_name = 'pmin', a, b))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `foo` must be length 5 (the number of rows) or one, not 8
```

For `function_name = 'sd'` the column should be `c(NA, 1.41, 0, NA, 2.828)` and the `min` and `pmin` should be `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1)`. I'm 100% sure the error has something to do with the `list/unlist`, but any other way I try it I end up with an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you what.  You needed to perform a row wise operation on the two vectors, thus I used the `apply` function.  This should work for any number of equal length vectors.

```
# Setup dataframe
a <- 1:5
b <- c(0, 4, 3, 0, 1)
c <- c(5:1)
d <- c(2, 0, 1, 0, 4)
#df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d) #not used

FUNexcludeZero <- function(function_name, ...){
  # Match function name 
  FUN <- match.fun(function_name)
  #combine the vectors into a matrix
  df<-cbind(...)

  #remove 0 from rows and apply function to the rows
  compiledVals <- apply(df, 1, function(x) { x<-x[x!=0] 
    FUN(x)})
  return(compiledVals) 
}

FUNexcludeZero(function_name = 'sd', a, b)
#[1]       NA 1.414214 0.000000       NA 2.828427
FUNexcludeZero(function_name = 'min', a, b)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 1
```